# Displaying Reminders page from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a PHP program for adding and viewing reminders. The add page works, but I'm having some trouble displaying them properly. How should I code this to only get the actual data? Also, how could I put this into an HTML table? (i.e. column for name, description, and date; rows are the retrieved data)

Thanks

When I open the file in my browser I get this as an output:

> Array ( [reminderID] => 14 [reminderName] => Test [reminderDescript] => Test_Descript [reminderDate] => 2012 05 7 )

Code:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Reminder List</h1>
        <table align ="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM reminder_event';
        $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                print_r($row);
            }
        ?>
  </table>
  <p><a href='reminder_add.php'>Add Reminder</a></p>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Consider also separating all your functions, including your queries, into separate include files, instantiate the class/function into a variable then echo that variable into the proper HTML location.  Makes for cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is a *diagnostic tool* for debugging, not to be used for real output.  Instead, output HTML to a table using the array keys fetched from your row.

```
// Open a table
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // Output each row
  echo "<tr>
   <td>{$row['reminderName']}</td>
   <td>{$row['reminderDescript']}</td>
   <td>{$row['reminderDate']}</td>
  </tr>";
}
// Close the table
echo "</table>";
```

Better still, escape each of the values for HTML output with [`htmlspecialchars()`] (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before output to prevent cross-site scripting attacks and broken HTML if characters like `< > &` are encountered in the values.

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // Encode all values for HTML output
  $name = htmlspecialchars($row['reminderName']);
  $desc = htmlspecialchars($row['reminderDescript']);
  $date = htmlspecialchars($row['reminderDate']);

  // Then output the encoded values
  echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$desc</td><td>$date</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

To:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['reminderID'];
  echo $row['reminderName'];
  echo $row['reminderDescript'];
  echo $row['reminderDate'];
}
```

You can echo those values out in whatever HTML you'd like. So, for example, if you want it in a table you would do something like this:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<td>" . $row['reminderID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['reminderName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['reminderDescript'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['reminderDate'] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

You can clean that up a bit to take some (or all) of the HTML out of the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Reminder List</h1>
    <table>
        <thead><tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>description</td><td>date</td></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM reminder_event';
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['reminderID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['reminderName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['reminderDescript']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['reminderDate']; ?></td>
            </tr>
           <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  <p><a href='reminder_add.php'>Add Reminder</a></p>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```